# Orthogonal distribution to parallel vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold. A vector field $X$ on $M$ is called **parallel** if the Levi-Civita connection $D_YX$ vanishes for every choice of $Y$. I already know that given $k$ parallel vector fields $X_1,...,X_k$ the distribution $\mathcal{D}$ spanned by these vector fields is integrable. I'm trying to prove that the orthogonal distribution $\mathcal{D}^\bot$ is integrable.

**My attempt**

Clearly, given a point $m\in M$:
$$\mathcal{D}^\bot_m=(X_1|_m)^\bot \cap ... \cap (X_k|_m)^\bot.$$
So, since the intersection of integrable distributions is integrable, I just need to prove the $k=1$ case:
$$\mathcal{D}^\bot_m=(X|_m)^\bot.$$
Basically, by Frobenius theorem, I have to prove that given two vector fields $V,W\bot X$, then $[V,W]\bot X$. My idea was to use the compatibility of Levi-Civita connection with the metric to show that $g([V,W],X)$ has to be constant:
$$U(g([V,W],X))=g(D_U[V,W],X)$$
and here I'm stuck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Try using torsion-freeness to write $[V,W]=D_VW-D_WV$ and then exploit compatibility with the metric to analyze $g([V,W],X)$ directly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Lately, I've been giving up too early and I don't know why...

Comment: You're welcome. For this exercise, things get tricky if you don't have the right idea how to start ...